# First Push notification disappears after locking the screen

Tags: ios, push-notification

If my app receives a push notification right after locking the screen, the very first one disappears after half of a second.  (Actually, I can see it appearing and disappearing)

The following ones are displayed on the screen correctly. I can reproduce this all the time. First one disappears and the followings remain on the screen.

I have verified that the state of the app when the notification is received is "background" and I am not calling never [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

so... I am lost!

Any clue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: your going to have to show some code otherwise we would just be guessing

Comment: That's the cool thing. Even commenting all the AppDelegate to the minimum and the main view controller just displaying the screen.. once is locked the phone, first notification is missing.

Comment: There is no code to display :(

Comment: this guy has the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861457/why-push-notification-disappears-from-lock-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already know what's happening.

Whenever you call a method from the APS, it will trigger the system to show the Register Alert. Even the `cancelAllLocalNotifications` method will make it appear.

So before calling any of them, make sure the user granted the use of push notifications.

Comment: Can you please describe what happened in more detail?

Comment: Please let us know more info!  I'm having the same problem but I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer

Answer (score 1):

It is either because you put the number of notifications to 0 in your code like

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

Or in you Notification payload, you have a the badge property set to 0

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 0,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the "first notification disappears" problem because I was calling a "local" notification inside my didReceiveRemoteNotification handler.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LOCALNOTIF" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);    
}
```

It looks like the local notification cancels the other one.  I removed the local notification and the problem was gone.